# show event by filter (FullCalendar)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, fullcalendar

I would like to access my calendar , show only the data determined belonging select that event.

Example : I want to see all Peter Dentist events

```
<select class="form-control" id="doctor">
<option value="0">Selecione</option>
<option value="1">Peter</option>
<option value="2">Antonio</option></select> 

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

My code looks like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                timezone: "local",
                ignoreTimezone: false,
                editable: true,
                startEditable: true,
                selectable: true,
                allDay: false,
                eventLimit: true,

                events:
                        {
                            url: 'agenda.json',
                            type: 'get',
                            data:
                                    {
                                    },
                            success: function (reply) {
                                console.log(reply);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert('Error!');
                            },
                            color: '#008000', 
                            textColor: 'white', 
                            allDayDefault: false
                        }...
```

How could I do it , where to access the page , select the make and only show the events related to the selected person ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript change function like this to get the value from the select and redirect to the page with the doctor id assigned to `$_GET['doctor']`.

```
$("#doctor").change(function() {
    doctorID = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var url = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    url += "?doctor=" + doctorID; 
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Then on your page you can do a check for the value (I do not know jsp so I can only show example in php) and if your value is set you can echo it out to your pages Javascript.

```
if(isset($_GET['doctor'])) {
    echo "var doctorID = " . $_POST['doctor'] . ";";
}
```

Then in your calendar you can get that id and add it to your events url to include in your query.

```
events: {
        url: "events.php?doctorID=" + doctorID
}
```

Comment: Now I tried and did not work. I am using jsp , I will study it.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning , I changed my code.
I need only work with this line :

```
events: '/agenda.json?cod=' + doctorID,
```

This line is within the  `$ ( '# calendar " ) . FullCalendar ( { ...`

When I put "1" in hand, it works perfectly :

```
events: '/agenda.json?cod=' + 1,
```

So I wanted to know how to set a variable using the select on change below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="doctor"><option value="0">Selecione</option> <option value="1">Peter</option><option value="2">Antonio</option></select>
```

I tried it , but could not pass the variable :

```
$("#doctor").change(function() {
doctorID = $(this).find(":selected").val();
```

});

As I enter the above code within the :`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({...`